# Is there an equivalent class like ITestResult(using testng) that is available with just JUnit?

Tags: java, junit4, extentreports, data-driven-tests, selenium-extent-report

I am currently using ExtentReport with TestNG to get the results of my test. I am now restricted to using only JUnit so I was wondering how I would convert my current code to have the same functionality without using TestNG

I have seen examples of others using either TestWatcher or RunListener but I am not really sure how to implement it for what I need. Especially being new to everything that I am using

```
@BeforeTest
 public void setup() {
     htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(new File(fileLocation));
     htmlReporter.loadXMLConfig(new File(FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getReportConfigPath()));
     reports = new ExtentReports();
     reports.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
}

@AfterTest
public void cleanup() {
    reports.flush();
}

@BeforeMethod
public void register(Method method) {
    String testName = method.getName();
    testInfo = reports.createTest(testName);

}

@AfterMethod
public void captureStatus(ITestResult result) {
    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
        testInfo.log(Status.PASS, "Test: " + result.getName() + " passed");
    } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        testInfo.log(Status.PASS, "Test: " + result.getName() + " failed");
        testInfo.log(Status.FAIL, "Test FAILURE: " + result.getThrowable());
    } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
        testInfo.log(Status.PASS, "Test: " + result.getName() + " skipped");
    }
}
```

`

I would like to repoduce the same results from these functions without the use of ITestResult and the rest of the testNG annotations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you will want to do is create a rule for handling test results. This rule will be created as a TestWatcher, then you will override its failed and succeeded methods.
Example:

```
@Rule
public TestWatcher watchman = new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
        // Handle logging of failing tests
        System.out.println("Fail!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded(Description description) {
        // Handle logging of succeeding tests
       System.out.println("Success!");
    }
};
```

The description parameter contains information about the failing class http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/Description.html

As for the method annotations, the following annotations are the TestNG - JUnit 4 equivalents:

@BeforeTest - @BeforeClass

@AfterTest - @AfterClass

@BeforeMethod - @Before

@AfterMethod - @After

The following code demonstrates how you could structure your test class:

```
public class MyTestClass {
    @Rule
    public TestWatcher watchman = new TestWatcher() {
        @Override
        protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
            // Handle logging of failing tests
            System.out.println("Fail!");
        }

        @Override
        protected void succeeded(Description description) {
            // Handle logging of succeeding tests
            System.out.println("Success!");
        }
    };

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        //Some setup before all test methods
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void cleanup() {
        // Some cleanup after all test methods
    }

    @Before
    public void register() {
        // Some setup before each test method
    }

    @Test
    public void succeedingTest() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void failingTest() {
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```